# How to delete all .jar file into a directory using Ant?

Tags: java, ant

I am pretty new to ant and I would delete all the .jar files that are into a directory.

Can I do something like it to do it?

```
<delete file="../Release/*.jar" />
```

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: What did you try? Which error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation

```
<delete>
  <fileset dir=".." includes="Release/*.jar"/>
</delete>
```

should do the job.

See the examples of the [Delete Task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
<delete>
    <fileset dir="../Release/" includes="*.jar"/>
  </delete>
```

ANT Documentation is very easy to follow. Please learn using this [link](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html)